# without mocking method how to return mock instance of another class

Tags: methods, java-8, mocking, instance

This is my Java class:

```
public final class KeywordHelpers{
  private KeywordHelpers(){}

  public static KeywordHelper createKeywordHelper(KeywordData keywordData){
   try{
    switch (keywordData.tooltype){
    case ToolType.CheckboxConfigurableTool:
      return new CheckboxKeywordHelper(keywordData);
    case ToolType.BloodPressureTool:
      return new BloodPressureKeywordHelper(keywordData);
    case ToolType.FixValueTool:
      return new FixValueKeywordHelper(keywordData);
    case ToolType.NumericTool:
    return new NumericKeywordHelper(keywordData);
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported keyword tool type: '" + Short.toString(keywordData.tooltype) +
      "' in keyword with id '" + keywordData.versioned.id + "' and term '" + keywordData.term + "'.");
    }
  }catch (SpiderException e){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not read keyword information for keyword with id '" + keywordData.versioned.id + "' and term '" + keywordData.term + "'.", e);
  }catch (XMLStreamException e){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not read keyword information for keyword with id '" + keywordData.versioned.id + "' and term '" + keywordData.term + "'.", e);
  }
 }
}
```

I want to mock and return my own instance when this class call

> return new CheckboxKeywordHelper(keywordData);

I try this in different ways.But not working for me.

I can't mock createKeywordHelper method.Because i want to check Switch-case

I use only mockito. and using testng,java 8

Comment: Take a look at [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock), this library allows mocking constructors and static methods.

Comment: In this project I can't use PowerMock

Comment: The problem is that you can't Mock constructors or static methods using Vanilla Mockito. You can either use  PowerMockito, do bytecode injection by yourself, or [modify your code](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-constructor/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we have to use power mockito.Unless we can't mock constructor.